# Magento Admin Module Controllers - Loading another action

Tags: magento, module, controller, admin

I am trying to create a new module for Magento that is only visible from the Admin Area.

I have successfully created the module and have now created a controller called 'editproducts'. In this controller I have indexAction and testAction.

When I go to /quickedit/editproducts/  it loads the indexAction from the controller perfectly fine, however when I go to /quickedit/editproducts/test/ it is redirecting to the dashboard and not calling the testAction. From the tutorials I have seen I appear to have set everything  up correctly.

My config.xml file:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Test_Quickedit>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Test_Quickedit>
</modules>

<global>
    <helpers>
        <quickedit>
            <class>Test_Quickedit_Helper</class>
        </quickedit>  
    </helpers>
</global>        

<admin>
    <routers>
        <the_name_of_this_element_is_not_important_it_should_be_unique>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Test_Quickedit</module>
                <frontName>quickedit</frontName>
            </args>
        </the_name_of_this_element_is_not_important_it_should_be_unique>
    </routers>
 </admin>

<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <menu1 translate="title" module="quickedit">
            <title>Test</title>
            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
            <children>
                <menuitem1 module="quickedit">
                    <title>Edit Products</title>
                    <action>quickedit/editproducts</action>
                </menuitem1>
            </children>                
        </menu1>
    </menu>
<acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <catalog>
                        <children>
                            <quickedit_editproducts>
                                <title>Edit Products</title>
                            </quickedit_editproducts>
                        </children>
                    </catalog>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>    
</config>
```

My EditproductsController.php

```
class Test_Quickedit_EditproductsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
    echo 'edit products';
}

public function testAction()
{
    echo 'test';
}
}
```

Comment: how did you generate the url for testAction? it needs to be generated from code as it needs key (can't be accessed directly ny changing the url from browser)

Comment: What is the path to your EditproductsController?  If you set up an exit after you echo 'test' does it do anything different?

Comment: Hi ivantedja, Where do I have to generate URLs? I followed a number of tutorials for creating a module and none of them mentioned generating URLs manually.

Comment: Hi Nate, my EditproductsController is in code/community/Test/Quickedit/controllers/   also what is odd is if I go to /quickedit/editproducts/ it works but by going to /quickedit/editproducts/index/ it does not, is that normal?

Comment: in your config.xml, try changing your <action>quickedit/editproducts</action> into <action>quickedit/editproducts/edit</action>, is it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just because of the URL which you are redirecting does not contain the Key

If you check the admin modules URL then you see a key is also added in the URL so in order to generate the correct URL use the below code.

```
$URL = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("mymodule/adminhtml_mycontroller/myaction/",array("param1"=>1,"param2"=>2));
```

or

```
$URL = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("mymodule/adminhtml_mycontroller/myaction/");
```

Hope this helps!!